# Ask the key binding problem between xterm bash and tmux

Tags: bash, tmux, xterm

- To get `TAB` and `ctrl-i` to do different things.
  I added the following configuration to my `xterm` and `bash` configuration files, and everything worked fine

```
XTerm.vt100.translations: #override \n\
    Ctrl <Key>I: string("\033[a5i")
```

```
bind -m vi-insert -x '"\e[a5i": echo aa'
```

- But when I ran `bash` in tmux, the above configuration didn't work properly, and when I hit `ctrl-i`, instead of executing the `echo` command, screen printed out `5i`
- I tried to perform this binding in `tmux`, but the results were not satisfactory

  Where `^[[1;2A5i` is the key sequence of `ctrl-i` I got using the `read` command

```
bind-key -n ^[[1;2A5i 'send-keys \033[a5i'
```

Answer (score 1):

tmux doesn't understand this key sequence. You can make it do so by adding it as a user key and then making that key send the sequence to panes inside tmux:

```
set -s user-keys[0] "\e[a5i"
bind -n User0 send Escape "[a5i"
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, but when I press `ctrl-i` in bash, I can trigger the binding, but it still prints `5i `more